# Use of GetLinkForce or GetLinkTorque

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

In my gazebo plugin, I have to use the function

```
virtual math::Vector3 gazebo::physics::Joint::GetLinkForce ( unsigned int   _index) const pure virtual
```

or

```
virtual math::Vector3 gazebo::physics::Joint::GetLinkTorque ( unsigned int  _index) const pure virtual
```

These functions should return the force applied at the centre of mass of a link; the problem is that this functions are pure virtual, so I must define them.
I could use the ODEJoint class (that inherits from Joint class): this owns the above functions, but only virtual.

I don't understand how to use the ODEJoint class, nay how to include this class in my plugin.

Can I use this functions without having ODEJoint?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12864/use-of-getlinkforce-or-getlinktorque/) by [gabri89](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2451/gabri89/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
I solved the proble adding

```
joint1->SetProvideFeedback(1);
```

command. So I can use GetLinkForce without problem.

---

Originally posted by [gabri89](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2451/gabri89/) with karma: 19 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0